# Magento 2 : Switch also are different in Magento?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have a problem, I made a switch case in my ajax.js file but even if the values fit a case, this is always the default case which is return,

someone has an idea why?

> There my code :
>
> app/code/Vendor/CustomerZipCode/view/frontend/web/js/ajax.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/url'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    template,
    url
) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ajaxurl = url.build('customerzipcode/zipcode');
        $('#zip_btn').val("not clicked");
        $('#zip_btn').on('click', function () {
            let Zip = $('#zip_txt').val();
            $('#zip_btn').val("clicked");
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {zipcode : Zip},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#test').removeClass('hideme');
                let displayzip ="You enter "+data['ZipCode']+" as zipcode <br/>";
                let fullchoice="You can choice between delivery or store pickup (for order over 200$)";
                let partialchoice="You can choice between delivery or store pickup, both for order over 200$";
                let nochoice="You are eligible only for store pickup for order over 200$";
                let html;
                console.log(data['ZipCode']);
                switch(data['ZipCode']){
                    case 11222 || '11222':
                        html=fullchoice
                        break;
                    case 11211 || '11211':
                        html=fullchoice
                        break;
                    case 11249 || '11249':
                        html=fullchoice
                        break;
                    default:
                        html=nochoice
                }
                $('#test p').html(displayzip+html);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sumit has fixed but not explained, you are writing the switch statement incorrectly. Rather than use `||` you should write a new case. Try replacing your switch with this:

```js
switch(data['ZipCode']){
    case '11222':
    case '11249':
    case '11211':
        html=fullchoice
        break;
    default: 
       html=nochoice
}
```

This is 'vanilla' JS and Magento have not changed how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is issue with the Switch statement in your code. Update your js with below code and give a try.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/url'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    template,
    url
) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ajaxurl = url.build('customerzipcode/zipcode');
        $('#zip_btn').val("not clicked");
        $('#zip_btn').on('click', function () {
            let Zip = $('#zip_txt').val();
            $('#zip_btn').val("clicked");
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {zipcode : Zip},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#test').removeClass('hideme');
                let displayzip ="You enter "+data['ZipCode']+" as zipcode <br/>";
                let fullchoice="You can choice between delivery or store pickup (for order over 200$)";
                let partialchoice="You can choice between delivery or store pickup, both for order over 200$";
                let nochoice="You are eligible only for store pickup for order over 200$";
                let html;
                console.log(data['ZipCode']);
                switch(data['ZipCode']){
                    case '11222': 
                    case '11211': 
                    case '11249': 
                        html=fullchoice 
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        html=nochoice
                }
                $('#test p').html(displayzip+html);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: There is no need to repeat the contents of each `case`, you can write that as:

`case '11222':case '11211':case '11249':html=fullchoice; break;default:html=nochoice`. I can't add new lines in a comment but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Yes Ben, Great thanks.
You mean I can add the code like `case '11222': case '11211': case '11249': html=fullchoice break; default: html=nochoice` for above example.

Comment: it will work also in Magento ? as magento is kind of ... special ... ?

Comment: It can work with Magento as well. 
Also, I've optimized the code as per Ben suggests.

Comment: The switch statement is pure JS, Magento have not changed this at all @SylvainMichel